# Using libusb.c without success

Tags: c++, usb, libusb

I am using Dev-C++. I try to list my usb connected devices. I downloaded a lib called libusb-1.0.21.tar and untar it. I tried to test some of the examples that came with it (testlibusb.c) but I always get errors like "undefined reference to libusb_get_ss_endpoint_companion_descriptor".

1. I just copied the usblib.c into the include folder and modified this include "libusb.c" to include  in testusblib.c. Did not work
2. I added this "library path" to the configuration. Did not work either.
3. I opened this lib and saw a lots of CALLs to this procedures and I downloaded and installed Zadig 2.2 thinking (maybe wrongly) that I needed some drivers or dll's installed. No success.

What do you recommend? What else should I try?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Maybe it has a package manager you can use to install libusb instead of trying to figure out how to compile the library yourself.

Comment: Win 10. Now I am struggling with the WDK, as suggested by some one in this same forum, the problem is that I don't want to buy "MS development visual studio" and install a huge white elephant in my computer.

Comment: I suggest installing MSYS2 and using the libusb package that it has.  I don't know about Dev-C++.

Comment: Interesting!... A Unix emulator for windows... I shall take a look, but for this project it is not very useful as I wish to develop a graphic interface running on windows platforms.